# Float three parent and child divs on the same line

Tags: html, css

I've created, three images which have text overlayed on top (each in a div). I'd like to arrange these on the same line.

```
<div style="position: relative; background: url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/web-based-crm.png); width: 282px; height: 125px; width:282;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0em; left: 0.7em; width: 282px; height: 125; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; font-size: 25px; font-family: Arial; float: left;">
        <p>Maximise<br />
            marketing ROI<br />
            with lead tracking</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="position: relative; background: url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/crm-software-image.png); width: 282px; height: 125px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0.5em; left: 0.7em; width: 282px; height: 125; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; font-size: 25px; font-family: Arial; float: left;">
        <p>Save time with<br />
            automatic reports</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; background: url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/crm-systems-image.png); width: 282px; height: 125px;">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0em; left: 0.7em; width: 282px; height: 125; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; font-size: 25px; font-family: Arial;">
        <p>Fast adoption<br />
            with a simple<br />
            user interface</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm unsure of the correct way to do this, float? display:inline?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/f1g7pswb/

Comment: `float:left;` works fine. Is there any reason why you didn't go with that?

Comment: Both would work. I'd personally go with the `display:inline-block` in this instance.

Comment: @Jaw.sh because it doesn't work, see - http://jsfiddle.net/f1g7pswb/1/

Comment: It does work. It's wrapping to the next line because the container is too small. Grow that cell.

Comment: This is embarrassing

Comment: If you make your comment as an answer I can accept and close this Fiddle.